# Trouble With a Triangulation of the Torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, triangulation

On pg. 133 of Rotman's *Introduction to Algebraic Topology*, we have a figure [image]

which claims to be a triangulation of the torus.

Now a triangulation of a topological space is defined as

> **Definition.** A **triangulation** of a topological space $X$ is a finite simplicial complex $K$ (in some Euclidean space) along with a homeomorphism $h:|K|\to X$.

I interpret the picture as a simplicial complex $K$ whose members are each of the little triangles along with all their edges and vertices. To claim that the given figure is a triangulation, we need to produce a homeomorphism $h:|K|\to T$, where $T$ denotes the torus.

One way to give a map from $|K|$ to $T$ is by seeing $T$ as the quotient space formed by identifying the left and the right edges and the top and the bottom edges (the usual way of making a torus from a rectangular piece of paper), and having the map $h:|K|\to T$ as the quotient map.

But this quotient map is not a homeomorphism since it is not a bijection.

I must be missing something obvius.

Comment: The map is clearly onto, can you find two different points mapping to the same point?

Comment: Yes. In particular, the four corners get mapped to the same point. Which is a problem because this means that the map is not a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here on this picture some simplexes are identified. When you give names to different vertices, it will look as follows
[image]

Comment: The diagram suggests the same kind of identification I had mentioned in the OP. The quotient space under the identification is the torus. My problem is that I cannot imagine a simplicial complex whose underlying space is homoeomorphic to the torus. Can you please address this? Thanks.

Comment: @caffeinemachine, there are eight (abstract) vertices $1,2,\dots9$, twenty seven edges $(12), (13), (14), (15), (17), (19)$, $(23), (25), (26), (27), (28)$... and eighteen triangles $(125),(139), (145)$.....

Comment: Oh. So this diagram is actually representing an abstract simplicial complex rather than a (geometric) simplicial complex. And we have a theorem which says that any abstract simplicial complex admits a geometric realization. Is this what is going on here?

Comment: @caffeinemachine, yes, and geometric realization is that we can _define_, this is not a theorem